# Array contains less elements than it's length. Why?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Quite simply as the title says, while using Three.js I came across an error where the array.length property had the value of 9, but the array only contained 4 objects. See the attached image from console - I've highlighted the relevent lines. I have no idea what to make of this, I never seen it before and didn't know it was possible.

The array is created by adding objects to the Three.js THREE.Group class... maybe it's a quirk of that code, but even then I didn't think it was possible for an arrays length to be longer or shorter than the elements it contains. Any ideas what's happening here and why?

[image]

Comment: It does show a length of 9, and then 9 Mesh objects inside of the array, but when you expand it there are only 4. This means that between the time you console.log'd the array and the time you expanded it in the console, the contents have changed. Might I suggest using `arr.forEach` instead of the `for` loop, and also consoling the Mesh entries inside the loop to prove what's happening a bit more.

Comment: Can you also `console.log(JSON.stringify(pivot.children))`.

Comment: Note the little blue `[i]` next to the output - this should clue you in that the contents are evaluated as you "expand" the array to view it, as @CharlieSchliesser stated.

Comment: Please read the guidelines and don't post pictures of code or errors

Comment: It looks like you're examining the 9th element in an array that contains an array with 4 mesh objects.

Comment: Hang on Charlie... you're saying something that is written to console can change and update after it's written?! I thought console was a log of things at the time as they are. I'm confused. Chaz - not sure what you're talking about. Possum - I also explained in words but image conveys much better.